# LINQ order-by issue

Tags: .net, sql, linq, c#-4.0, sql-order-by

I have a weird issue with LINQ.

I have a table that needs to be ordered by 4 columns...out of a total of 8 columns.
The rows in this table are chronological (ordered by DateTime).

Lets say the 8 cols in table are A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

I need the table ordered by F, E, D, B

F=> string

E=> string

D=> string

B=> DateTime

i have written the following LINQ-

```
List<Rows> OrderedListOfRows = listOfRows.OrderBy(i => i.F).ThenBy(i=>i.E).ThenBy(i=>i.D).ThenBy(i=>i.B);
```

I am performing operations on this sequence, and getting the required result. However, I noticed a bug.

If my sample input rows for D is "input1", "input2", "input3"....."input10", "input11"

the orderby function sorts the entries as: "input1", "input10", "input11", "input2", "input3"...because D is a string.

However I want the original order preserved (which is not a problem if I do not have "input10", "input11", etc....

How do i achieve this?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I have tried my best to explain the issue. If there is anything else, leave me a comment.

Edit: I resolved this issue. I am joining the new list with the old list on that column, so that my order is preserved. This is not posted in any of the suggested "duplicate" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to order by the number in string, you can try this:

```
int MyOrderBy(string str)
{
  Regex reg=new Regex("\\d+");
  Match m=reg.Match(str);
  if(m.Success) return int.Parse(m.Value);
  else return int.MinValue;
}
```

Then Orderby:

```
    List<Rows> OrderedListOfRows = listOfRows.OrderBy(i => MyOrderBy(i.F))
                                             .ThenBy(i=>MyOrderBy(i.E))
                                             .ThenBy(i=>MyOrderBy(i.D))
                                             .ThenBy(i=>i.B).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have predictable entries in D you can parse the string in your order by like so:

```
List<Rows> OrderedListOfRows = listOfRows
  .OrderBy(i => i.F)
  .ThenBy(i=>i.E)
  .ThenBy(i=>i.D.Substring(0,5))
  .ThenBy(i=>Convert.ToInt16(i.D.Substring(6)))
  .ThenBy(i=>i.B);
```